# How to evaluate the significance of the prediction of an svm classifier, when the train and test sets are separate datasets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, permutation, svm

I'm using sklearn and trying to assess whether it is possible to predict the labels of my test set using a model fitted to my train set (the train and test sets are two different datasets).

This is what I did so far:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

And my questions are the following:

1. how do I get a « prediction score » (I assume that I would have to somehow compare y_predicted and y_test)?
2. how can I compute an **empirical** p-value to evaluate the significance of the prediction score, using a null distribution based on permutations of the test dataset?

If the train and test sets were drawn from the same dataset, I would use the following:

```
cv = KFold(n_splits=5)
score, permutation_scores, pvalue = sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score(svc, X, y, cv=cv, scoring = « accuracy », n_permutations=1000)
```

But I’m lost in the present case, because I have two sets of Xs and ys (i.e. X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test), and an already-fitted model.

Comment: what is the nature of labels (binary, categorical, ...)? How the class balance in both sets look like? What exactly do you want to measure (there are hundreds of ways how a p-value might not tell the true story)?

Comment: @Marat The labels are binary, and the classes are balanced in both the train and test sets. What I'm trying to test is whether there are shared representations between my train and test sets - if yes, I assume that it would be possible to train a classifier on on my train dataset and have it perform well (i.e. above empirical chance-level) on my test dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution

I have an already fitted model (to my train set), and here I am trying to predict the ground-truth labels of my test set with it:

```
score = model.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Then, I shuffle the ground-truth labels of my test set and try to predict them 1000 times, to get an estimate of the empirical chance level:

```
n_permutations = 1000

permutation_scores = np.zeros(n_permutations)

for i in range(n_permutations):
    y_test_permuted = shuffle(y_test)
    permutation_score = model.score(X_test, y_test_permuted)
    permutation_scores[i]=permutation_score

permutation_scores = np.array(permutation_scores)
```

And then, I compute a p-value to estimate whether the score I get when trying to predict the ground-truth test labels is significantly above chance-level:

```
pvalue = (np.sum(permutation_scores >= score) + 1.0) / (n_permutations + 1)
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  The training features stay the same but you are shuffling the ground truth labels.  What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The purpose is to evaluate the performance of an already fitted (to my train set) model on my (independent) test set. Here, I am shuffling the ground-truth labels of my test set, to evaluate whether the accuracy I get when trying to predict ground-truth test labels is significantly above chance-level. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see.  Yes that's perfectly fine.  Thanks for the clarification!  I think you should add these details to your answer.